# Every time I open my project I have to create virtual directories

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis

I am currently working on a solution which has an ASP.NET application and a Web Service.  Whenever I open this solution I get the message that the virtual directories for this project have not yet been created and must be to continue.  The problem is, if I hit OK, it cannot create the directories because they already exist and then I cannot load the project.  Looking in IIS I can see that the virtual directory exists in C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/ProjName.  If I delete this from IIS, I can then open the project, but it creates the virtual directory in C:/*location of project folder*.  When it uses the project's location, I am not able to connect to the site or the web service.

The same thing happens on XP with IIS 5.1, VS 2010 and Server 2003 with IIS 6.0, VS 2010.  Similarly, it happens on colleague's machines, so I am convinced that it is a setting in VS, and not IIS or my machine.

Right now, my solution is to delete the virtual directories, open the VS solution, delete the virtual directories, and publish the projects with the publish toolbar in visual studio (not the web tab in project properties).

I fear that I've at some point messed up a setting on both of the projects, but it has been some time since I've been working around this.  I've scoured all of the settings and I can't find anything that fixes this behaviour.  I need to pass the project along to someone else, and I feel as if the work around instructions may be confusing so I want to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do things similarly back in the days when VS didn't have its own dev server - re: directly work on web projects in a local version of IIS (if memory serves, this was called "Personal Web Server" or PWS - am I advertising my age?)

Anyway, I haven't (thankfully) done that since VS (2005?) got its own dev server...

Try this process in VS 2010:

You can *develop* your solution on any local folder in your file system. You can run/debug your solution from VS (ctrl f5 or f5 respectively) - it will use VS dev server by default. Your development machine doesn't even need to have IIS...

After you are done developing and debugging (using VS and its dev server), you can *publish* to IIS or even to some other "publish folder" in your (local) file system, and simply copy the files to whatever (local/remote) IIS virtual (*ASP.NET application*) folder you prefer.

Comment: I'm aware of this and I used VS development servers for a while. However, my code is making some calls to .exe files, and they perform differently when called from my project hosted in IIS vs a development server.  For some reason when I use IIS there are credential issues and sometimes resource discarding issues which I need to resolve.